# What if a user keep asking all his question by editing only question?

Tags: discussion, edits, asking-questions, community-standards

If notoriously a user ask one question, and then edit the same question for his second (of-course getting answer of first question is not a matter here) question. And he can ask 5 question a day by doing that.

Again on another day he does the same. What action can be taken agains that user if some one notice that?

Comment: flag for moderator attention, explain them the situation. Also add a comment explaining the OP that what he is doing is wrong..

Comment: To add context: mods can rollback edits and lock posts from further editing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First ask that user to not ask another question in the existing question. If he does not respond and keep doing the same, just flag one of his question for moderators attention and explain it in brief.